# how can i access variables from one form to another

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am new to QT
I have one doubt regarding passing values between Forms.I have declared haar classifier in form1 and I need to access the same in form2.So I declared haar classifier in form2,but it shows multiple declaration of haar classifier cascade.So how can I pass variables between forms.I specified haar classifier using extern keyword then also it is not working.
I can not use SIGNAL and SLOT because i am not declared it in the button_click event.
When I call the haar classifier in from2 i need to load that XML file.
Can any one help me.

Comment: Passing values from UI to code and vice versa would be easiest with a SIGNAL/SLOT connection. Eventually you could also use a SIGNAL/SIGNAL connection to just set values in all given UI-Forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use SIGNAL-SLOT. `emit` the value from where to want to pass and that will be your SIGNAL. Then connect that SIGNAL with a SLOT which need that value. Your SLOT will be a method which will receive that value.